# PHP SQL Server Connection

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using SQL Server as my backend for program.when i am try to connect with database which not shows any type of errors,but it is not working.Which is not getting connection.

My code is like

```
mssql_connect('servername', 'db_user', 'db_password') or die('Error');
```

The funny thing is which is not connecting and also which is not show message Error.

How can we enable SQL Server configuration using php program  (what is the script for that.not manually). How could we know the actual status of SQL Server in server?

My application is working properly in local;the problem is about public hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turn on error_reporting in your php.ini. it might be some other section of code that is causing the issue, since you say that it doesn't go to die part. try checking first if it even goes to the mysql_connect() part. if possible post a part of your code around the mysql_connect.

Answer (score -1):

I would bet it is localhost, I have, nor do I ever wish to, see the database sitting on the same server as the website. Check in your hosting control panel for the proper connection string.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Actually which is not localhost.there is a problem when i am post the query.Sorry.Let me know what will be the problem for my question

Comment: If it works locally, then it has to be permissions/credential issues. Double check your username and password.

Comment: "I never wish to see the database sitting on the same server as the website" - that rules out all the hundreds of thousands of wordpress installations in the world then. Use what works for each situation. Having the database locally has it's advantages as well as the disadvantages you're already aware of.

Comment: Since most of the Wordpress instances are hosted, I actually doubt that they are on the same server. Physical separation of app and DB is a best practice in my opinion, and I stand behind my statement.